# UDP packet does not reach the application that is listening on Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I am sending a UDP packet from Arduino, the packet reach my server Ubuntu because it is possible to see it on tcpdump as you can see. But is never forwarded to my application that is listening on port 8888.
Someone has an idea of what is wrong on the packet?

My version of Ubuntu is:
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic-pae i686)

This is the `tcpdump`:

```
tcpdump -i 1 udp port 8888 -vv -X
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 byte                                                       s
19:06:20.179117 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 131)
    192.168.1.53.3333 > diskServer.8888: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 103
        0x0000:  4500 0083 0000 4000 4011 b6b1 c0a8 0135  E.....@.@......5
        0x0010:  c0a8 0133 0d05 22b8 006f 87d6 7465 7374  ...3.."..o..test
        0x0020:  2030 3132 3334 3536 3738 3930 2074 6573  .01234567890.tes
        0x0030:  7420 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3020 7465  t.01234567890.te
        0x0040:  7374 2030 3132 3334 3536 3738 3930 2074  st.01234567890.t
        0x0050:  6573 7420 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3020  est.01234567890.
        0x0060:  7465 7374 2030 3132 3334 3536 3738 3930  test.01234567890
        0x0070:  2074 6573 7420 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839  .test.0123456789
        0x0080:  3020 00                                  0..
```

This is the Listen port:

```
root@diskServer:~# netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 diskServer:mysql        *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 diskServer:ssh          flavix:53077            ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    144 diskServer:ssh          flavix:53028            ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 diskServer:ssh          192.168.1.107:54978     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 diskServer:ssh          192.168.1.107:55000     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8443               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8005          [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 diskServer:ntp          *:*
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*
udp        0      0 192.168.1.25:netbios-ns *:*
udp        0      0 diskServer:netbios-ns   *:*
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*
udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:netbios-dgm *:*
udp        0      0 diskServer:netbios-dgm  *:*
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*
udp        0      0 diskServer:8888         *:***
udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       [::]:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::20e:7bff:feac:ntp [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
```

Memory of UDP:

```
root@diskServer:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem
18066   24090   36132

root@diskServer:~# netstat -su
IcmpMsg:
    InType3: 10316969
    InType8: 18368
    OutType0: 18368
    OutType3: 10317030
Udp:
    211263 packets received
    10309092 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    10348446 packets sent
UdpLite:
IpExt:
    InMcastPkts: 24678
    InBcastPkts: 287164
    OutBcastPkts: 12685
    InOctets: -1
    OutOctets: -1
    InMcastOctets: 690984
    InBcastOctets: 48281994
    OutBcastOctets: 3170039
```

---

```
root@diskServer:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-apache-badbots  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-apache-overflows  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-apache-noscript  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-apache-badbots (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-apache-noscript (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

ufw is disabled.

Comment: Is your application really listening? What happens if you send the UDP packet from `DiskServer` to itself?

Comment: @Eric Thank you for your interest, i tried to send a UDP packet from diskServer to itself with netcat (echo -n “foo” | nc -4u -w1 diskServer 8888) , This is the result from my application: # ./rcvUDP
Waiting for data... on 8888Received packet from 192.168.1.51:56601
Data: “foo”▒v▒xݩ▒▒'v▒
Waiting for data... on 8888

Comment: Just an update, I see that this packer is received by a windows pc only if the WireShark monitoring is active at same time. I steel can't receive it on a ubuntu system, i tried also to upgrade to 14.04 without success..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the packet, that is wrong because the destination at Ethernet level was set to 0, this is the output of wireShark :

Ethernet II, Src: 74:69:69:2d:30:31 (74:69:69:2d:30:31), Dst: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00:00:00:00)

This is due to an hardware problem on my Arduino Board.

Thaks to all,
Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is probably in the ethercard library that was used. It does not properly handle ARP lookup for the destination, causing the all zeroes destination mac address (see https://github.com/jcw/ethercard/issues/181).

An alternative library which does work is Ethernet_UIP, which can be found at https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip and which has an example that sends UDP packets; I tested that example and it does work.